# Is the expression "sealed in" grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs

> Three 100 dollar bills were placed in an envelope, and then the envelope was
>   sealed.

I want to know whether it is possible to combine the two sentences above as follows:

> Three 100 dollar bills were sealed in an envelope.

I looked up some dictionaries, but I couldn't find the answer. It seems that this is grammatically incorrect as with the expression "water filled in a glass".

Comment: Since "sealed in" can be used as an alternative to "sealed up", in the sense of "secured" (to prevent access), there's nothing *syntactically* wrong with *The derelict houses were **sealed in in** 1985* (that was when the doors and windows were boarded up). So stretching a point, I'd say it's "grammatical" to say those bills were *sealed in in an envelope*. It's just clumsy.

Comment: The OP asks about "sealed in an envelope", (only one 'in'), which is absolutely fine, and often seen in UK English.

Comment: *Envelope* /ˈenvəˌloʊp/ is the noun, and *envelop* /ɪnˈveləp/ is the verb.  They’re spelled and pronounced differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with either of your sentences, but the most natural expression is:

> Three 100-dollar bills were placed in a **sealed envelope**.

It's assumed that the sentence means you put the bills into an envelope and then sealed it.

Interpreting the sentence literally (*"How did you put them into an envelope that was already sealed?"*) would make no sense—and nobody does so.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your second sentence needs to be:

> Three 100 dollar bills were sealed in an **envelope.**

I would say both are correct but the first sentence is a bit more logical and more compact.